# Alamofire certificate pinning not working

Tags: ios, swift, ssl-certificate, alamofire

I'm trying to implement certificate pinning using Alamofire.

I have added mydomain to "Exception Domains" in .plist file and set keys:

```
NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads: true
NSIncludesSubdomains: true
NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy: false
```

Then, I create SessionManager this way:

```
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "mydomain": .pinCertificates(certificates: [],
                                     validateCertificateChain: true,
                                     validateHost: true)
    ]

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration,
                                    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
```

When I run my app, all requests succeed, but the expected result is Alamofire rejecting them. I've set breakpoints to all "didReceiveChallenge" methods and they're not even executed.

When I change the configuration to

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "background")
```

Then cert pinning works as expected (rejecting all requests)

Anyone has an idea why it happens and how to fix it using default configuration?

Note: When I pass my .der file to certificates in .pinCertificates policy, background configuration also works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a reason - Wormholy. I had to remove this library to make cert pinning working